# How do I display all images in a firesbase storage file on android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I've got a app where users can upload images to 4 different folders in on fire base storage, I know I want to be able to view these images on the app but don't know how.

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this problem but here it is. I Have made a review app where users can submit images and reviews, I have gotten the review section to work fine and the uploading images to work so that each different company has its own file for images. I know want to be able to retrieve the images from the storage on fire base and print them into a recycler view but can't work out to do this. Any advice would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StorageReference to load Firebase storage image.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("folder_name");


// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(image );
```

For more details [Docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md)

Comment: ive tried this but when I click gallery it just goes to a white page showing the text view I have an no image view

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to list all storage files but if You know how you saving it in each folder you can easily show delete or whatever.Lets say you saved by number 1-100 you can for loop this to get download url and show in glide.

```
 storageRef.child("folderA/1.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new 
     OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
      Glide.load(uri)
    // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
}
 }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle any errors
}
 });
```

Comment: its saved as a random string so i cant do that

Comment: If You know how were you generating those random strings and any way to loop through them. Else there is no option right now that let you read database stroage from Firebase. You can post a request on firebase support

Comment: Usually the best practices is to know how you are saving it. Like for all users profile storage i use their id.jpg so if I need to clean up storage when user delete account. I can easily do that.